# How I do change the opacity of text as I scroll, but only when in view of the window?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My code example doesn't really work.. But what I'm trying to do is change the opacity of each text block from 0 to 1 as you scroll (But only when the text block is in view).
So when the first text block comes into view I change the opacity of it as I scroll and then once I reach the next text block, the first one has its opacity reduced to 0 and the next text block appears as I scroll.....

I have an example on a site of what I mean [here](https://centra.com/) - if you scroll down to the features section.

screenshot of the section I'm referencing:
[image]

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('.text-block').each(function () {
          $(this).css({
              opacity: function() {
                  var elementHeight = $(this).height(),
                  opacity = ((elementHeight - scrollTop) / elementHeight);
                  return opacity;
            }
      });
    });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.text-block {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>SCROLL DOWN</h1>
<div class="text-block">
  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.

Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.
</div>
<div class="text-block">
  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.

Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.
</div>
<div class="text-block">
  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.

Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.
</div>
<div class="text-block">
  Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus.

Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Sed porttitor lectus nibh.
</div>
```

Comment: You will probably find answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport#answer-31772470

Answer (score 0):

you can use intersection observer in javascript. Refer to this video
[Introduction to the Intersection Observer JavaScript API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8EYosX4NOo&t=1s&ab_channel=KevinPowell)